# Gradle sync failed: Support for builds using Gradle versions older than 2.6 was removed [...]. You are currently using Gradle version 2.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to build an old app I made in 2015. But I keep getting above error in Android Studio.

I tried bumping the version number to 2.6 or to 3.6.3 (as Android Studio suggested) but the message keeps appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio tries to download the appropriate version from jcenter, specifically from [this directory](https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/com/android/tools/build/gradle/). As you can see **it only has gradle versions up to 2.3.0**. So you will need to add another repository which has newer builds.

The fix is to change your module-levels build script **in all two places** from

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

to

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```